# Unable to Install R packages in Visual Studio Code

Tags: r, ggplot2, visual-studio-code, terminal

I wanted to use R in visual studio code and so I tried running some basic codes and it worked. But whenever I try to install any package (eg. ggplot2) from the R-Extension in the VsCode I get this error

> Installing package into 'C:/Users/krish/Documents/R/win-library/4.1'
> (as 'lib' is unspecified) Warning in install.packages(c("ggplot2"),
> repos = "https://cran.r-project.org/") :   'lib =
> "C:/Users/krish/Documents/R/win-library/4.1"' is not writable Error in
> install.packages(c("ggplot2"), repos = "https://cran.r-project.org/")
> :    unable to install packages Execution halted The terminal process
> "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.2\bin\R.exe '--silent', '--slave', '-e',
> 'install.packages(c('ggplot2'),repos='https://cran.r-project.org/')'"
> terminated with exit code: 1.
>
> Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

I have added r-library and r bin to env path following some other posts but it is not working.

Comment: It seems to think that `C:/Users/krish/Documents/R/win-library/4.1"' is not writable` Have you confirmed that the directory exists and is writable?

Comment: @DaveArmstrong How can I confirm whether it is writeable or not?

Comment: What operating system are you using?