# How do I install R packages from VSCode using global site-library

Tags: r, linux, visual-studio-code

I'm having trouble installing R packages from VSCode using the [R extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=REditorSupport.r)  v5.2.3. The directory `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library` that VSCode is trying to write to is not writeable. This is the directory that is used when I start R as root and install R packages from the console. This is where I want my R packages to live.

This is the error I get when using VSCode to install the R package [`here`](https://here.r-lib.org/). Note that I start VSCode as a normal user.

```
Executing task: /usr/bin/R --silent --slave -e install.packages(c('here'),repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/') 

Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages(c("here"), repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org/") :
  'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
Error in install.packages(c("here"), repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org/") : 
  unable to install packages
Execution halted

 *  The terminal process "/usr/bin/R '--silent', '--slave', '-e', 'install.packages(c('here'),repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')'" failed to launch (exit code: 1). 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72819165/unable-to-install-r-packages-in-visual-studio-code) describe the same error on windows. But with no solution...

So, is there a way to manage my R packages from VSCode using the global library `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`?

My Linux info:

```
~$ uname -rvmpo
5.15.0-48-generic #54~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 1 16:17:26 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And the R ditto:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint 20.3

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atlas/libblas.so.3.10.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atlas/liblapack.so.3.10.3

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=sv_SE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=sv_SE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=sv_SE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.1
```

Comment: @user2554330, I start VSCode as a normal user. Not root.

Comment: How about. if you specify lib? (Click the extensions icon at the left, on the R icon click the cog, go to extension settings, scroll down to R Lib Paths, add /usr/local/lib/R/site-library)

Comment: I don't use VSCode, but presumably it would allow you to (temporarily) set up R to run using `sudo R`.  Without that, I think you'll have to run VSCode under `sudo`.  Or you could use `sudo` to change the permissions on that directory, but that's a little risky.